# AWS Capistrano connection error

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, capistrano

I am trying my first deployment of rails app using Capistrano to AWS.

I am stumped at the following error. apparently connection issue for my ssh, though i could see both my public and private key files are present at the following location
/home/thanikkal/.ssh/config (got added wen i did ssh-add)
can anyone tell why this error is? or suggest further trouble shooting steps?

- executing `deploy:setup'

  - executing "mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/myapp /home/ubuntu/myapp/releases /home/ubuntu/myapp/shared /home/ubuntu/myapp/shared/system /home/ubuntu/myapp/shared/
    log /home/ubuntu/myapp/shared/pids"

  servers: ["ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com"]
  connection failed for: ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com (Errno::EISDIR: Is a directory - /home/thanikkal/.ssh/config)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have conflicting credentials in your "/home/thanikkal/.ssh/config"
You might want to remove and see if it works.

You also need to make sure the ssh key folder contains both public and private keys.

Comment: You right that really was the problem. Though I had that figured already. will mark your answer regardless :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try to deploy using your *pem* file.

Here are the instructions you should include into your deploy.rb file

```
default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
ssh_options[:auth_methods] = "publickey"
ssh_options[:keys] = ["/path/to/your/pem/file/cert.pem"]
```

Comment: No luck with those... :(  Btw, is the .pem extension important?