# How to authenticate with key file in capifony?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, capifony

I am trying to setup capifony. I am using this 
`ssh -i keyfile.pem username@servername.com` to authenticate on server from console. How I can configure capifony for this?

Comment: I have been found the answer for this question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057047/aws-capistrano-connection-error

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following configuration:

```
ssh_options[:user] = "username"
ssh_options[:keys] = ["/path/to/your/keyfile.pem"]
```